# Test a string against many regular expressions

Tags: regex, time-complexity

Consider an input string S of length *n*. An application must consider if S is matched by any of *m* regular expressions. Given the assumption that the particular regular expressions involved can be matched in time O(*n*), can all *m* expressions be tested faster than the trivial O(*mn*) approach of testing each expression in sequence? Additionally, if such an operation is possible, are there any libraries (any language) that implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really answers your question.

Here is a groovy script which can be used to test valid and invalid list of strings and test against certain regular expression.

```
def validList = ["9999","[9999]","9-9","[9-9]","09XYAB","ABXY","BA09YX"]
def invalidList = ["[999","9- ", "9-]", "9- 9","9[", "[999[", "09XYABC","1234", "A B"]
def pattern = ~/([09XYAB-]*)|([\[]([09XYAB-]*)([\]]))/
print "Verifying against the regex '${pattern}'\n"
print "Valid List Result(+ve tests)"
print "\n---------------------------------------------\n"
validList.each{
    if(pattern.matcher(it).matches()) {
        print it +"\ttest passed - Pattern matched\n"
    } else {
        print it +"\ttest failed - Pattern not matched\n"
    }
}
print "\n"
print "inValid List Result(-ve tests)"
print "\n---------------------------------------------\n"
invalidList.each{
    if(!(pattern.matcher(it).matches())) {
        print it +"\tTest Passed - Pattern not matched\n"
    } else {
        print it +"\tTest Failed - Pattern matched\n"
    }
}
```

One can be able to test on [console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)